# Hudson + Email Extension Plugin+ Add BCC and CC

Tags: hudson, hudson-plugins, hudson-api

I am using Email extension plugin with Hudson. There is only TO list option available with the plugin. Is there any way I can add CC and BCC options? Please guide.

Answer (score 3):

Not in Hudson, but I know that Jenkins had implemented this https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-6703. You can prefix the email address with "cc", like `cc:you@company.com`

Comment: thanks, also noticed this is in the info box when you click on the question mark